# How can list of values be changed insisde a map? (Java)

Tags: java

I have this kind of map:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

And I'm trying to edit one of my list's values. This is how I tried to achieve that:

```
map.get(key).toArray()[index] = newString;
```

I convert my list into an array and assign new String. But this line of code does nothing. Is there any solution to it? I think I can just create a new list which will have a different value, but I hope there is a simpler way to achieve that.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you converting the list into an array instead of just calling `put()` on it?

Comment: What exactly do you wanna do ? each key has a list against against it, you want to update some values in the list right ?

Comment: @azurefrog I tried to do that, but it requires me to put a new list.

Comment: @PriyakDey yes, I want to edit some values inside my list

Comment: @azurefrog It looks like OP is trying to modify content of list, not map. `List` doesn't have `put` method, OP is most likely looking for `set(index, element)`.

Comment: @Joni already gave a pretty good answer below then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List.toArray` method creates an array that is a **copy** of the list. You can use the `List.set` method to set an item at an index

```
List<String> list = map.get(key);
list.set(index, newValue);
```

or, without a temporary variable:

```
map.get(key).set(index, newValue);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was trying to do! Thank you very much for a quick answer!:)